# how to make many2one field readonly for user which is under specific group in open erp7?

Tags: python, security, odoo

I created module named hr_th having security group "group_thw_emp" I have field "employee_id" which is many2one field refer to hr_employee class. I tried following code in my xml

`<field name="employee_id" attrs= "{'readonly': [('groups','=','hr_th.group_thw_emp')]}"/>`

but I get error as :

`Uncaught Error: Unknown field groups in domain [['groups','=','hr_th.group_thw_emp']]`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a slightly tricky one.  Ideally you would do something like

```
attrs = {'readonly': [('employee_id.groups', 'contains', 'hr_th.group_thw_emp')]}
```

But as far as I know you can't do this. I don't believe the attribute expression evaluator supports contains.

The way I have worked around it is to extended or change the model and add a functional field that returns true if the employee is a member of the group you want and use it like this.

```
<field name="employee_is_in_thw_emp" invisible="1" />
<field name="employee_id" attrs="{'readonly': [('employee_is_in_thw_emp', '=', True)]}" />
```

This isn't great as you could end up with a lot of functional fields but I haven't found a better way yet.